# Issue with Bootstrap Footer

Tags: javascript, php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap for my app [here](http://crowdtesting.guru99.com/tester_registration.php).

I want to stick the footer till bottom of page as shown below

[image]
AS above, footer doesn't come at bottom of page.

I have searched stackoverflow and tried number of solutions but none resolves my problem. Please help

Answer (score 2):

try add following css

```
.footer-v1{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the class `navbar-fixed-bottom` its [part of boootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-bottom).

Example usage for your page:

`<div class="copyright navbar-fixed-bottom">`

Answer (score 0):

```
<footer role="contentinfo">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
footer{
   bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**JS**

```
(function ($) {

    var height = $('footer').height();
    //update the  value when page is loaded
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').css({"margin-bottom" : height });

    });

    //update the  value when the browser is resized (useful for devices which switch from portrait to landscape)
    $(window).resize(function () {
    $('body').css({"margin-bottom" : height });
    });

})(jQuery);
```